# exec fails to find files after root changed using pivot_root

Tags: c, chroot, linux-namespaces

I'm trying to experiment with namespaces and chroot emulation, and have succeeded in creating an environment that only has the new root in it (confirmed by a directory traversal), but for some reason, I can't seem to execute anything in it.

Here is a minimally reproducible example:

```
mkdir /jail
mkdir /jail/bin
mkdir /jail/usr
mkdir /jail/lib
cp /bin/bash /jail/bin
```

```
/* isoroot.c */
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sched.h> /* use clone */
#include <syscall.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sched.h>

#ifndef pivot_root
#define pivot_root(new, old) syscall(SYS_pivot_root, new, old)
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int res = 0;
    const char *new_root = "/jail";
    const char *old_root = "/oldroot";

    (void) argc;

    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)) { /* Must be executed with privileges. Don't forget this, or we basically blow up the system since we'll remove the real mount */
        fprintf(stderr, "unshare: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    if (mount(NULL, "/", NULL, MS_REC | MS_PRIVATE, NULL)) { /* Prevent shared propagation */
        fprintf(stderr, "mount: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    if (mount(new_root, new_root, NULL, MS_BIND, NULL)) { /* Ensure new_root is a mount point */ 
        fprintf(stderr, "mount: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    if (mkdir("/jail/oldroot", 0777)) { /* should be new_root/old_root */
        fprintf(stderr, "mkdir: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }

    /* Mount some things we need before we dismount the old root */
    /* /usr has /bin, /sbin, /lib, and /lib64 */
    res = mount("/usr", "/jail/usr", NULL, MS_BIND | MS_REC | MS_RDONLY, NULL);
    if (res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mount usr failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    if (pivot_root(new_root, "/jail/oldroot")) { /* Actually make it the new root */
        fprintf(stderr, "pivot_root: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    if (chdir("/")) { /* Switch to new root */
        fprintf(stderr, "chdir failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }

    if (umount2(old_root, MNT_DETACH)) { /* Unmount old root */
        fprintf(stderr, "umount2 failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    if (rmdir(old_root)) { /* Remove old mount point */
        fprintf(stderr, "rmdir failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    if (access("/bin/bash", X_OK)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bash4 not found: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        _exit(errno);
    }
    printf("Got all the way here\n");
    execvp("/bin/bash", argv);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(errno);
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wnull-dereference -Wformat=2 -Wshadow -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -std=gnu99 -pthread -O0 -g -Wstack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fwrapv -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -c isoroot.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wnull-dereference -Wformat=2 -Wshadow -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -std=gnu99 -pthread -O0 -g -Wstack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fwrapv -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -o isoroot *.o
```

What seems particularly strange is that the last `access` succeeds, indicating that `access` can find `/bin/bash`. However, `execvp` always fails with `No such file or directory`.

I'm assuming since that `access` is using the new namespace at this point, `exec` would too, but for some reason, that doesn't seem to hold here. Is there some trick to exec being able to find stuff after the root has been changed?

As a comparison, the example here does work in the sense that exec succeeds, but it doesn't really seem to pivot the root in that everything from the real root is still visible: https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0803.0/1805.html

```
chdir("/jail"); 
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS);
mount("/jail", "/jail", NULL, MS_BIND, NULL);
pivot_root("/jail", "/jail/old_root");
chdir("/");
mount("/old_root/bin", "bin", NULL, MS_BIND, NULL);
mount("/old_root/usr", "usr", NULL, MS_BIND, NULL);
mount("/old_root/lib", "lib", NULL, MS_BIND, NULL);
umount2("/old_root", MNT_DETACH);
exec("/busybox");
```

Using `ldd`, I've confirmed I should have everything needed to run something like `/bin/sh` as well. Both `/bin` and `/lib`, as well as `/lib64` are simply symlinks to folders in

```
# ldd /bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc99116000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007fd041cb9000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd041cb3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd041ade000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd041e3a000)
```

I tried manually adding the symlinks too, just in case, but I just get "Error: File already exists" when I do this at the end, just before exec:

```
    if (symlink("/bin", "/usr/bin")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "symlink failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    if (symlink("/lib", "/usr/lib")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "symlink failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    if (symlink("/lib64", "/usr/lib64")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "symlink failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
```

Trying to `mount` `/proc` and `/lib64` fail although `/bin` and `/lib` succeed (even though all of these except `/proc` are symlinks to `/usr/<dir>`

Comment: Probably missing shared libraries in `/lib`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I had tested with mounting some of those dirs as well, but it didn't work with that either. Example updated.

Comment: Run `ldd /bin/bash` to see exactly what shared libraries Bash needs to run, and ensure those exist in your chroot environment.

Comment: @larsks Ah, looks like I needed to add lib64 as well, still no joy though

Comment: I do not follow, you have to _copy_ the libraries to _inside_ chroot. `if (symlink("/lib64", "/usr/lib64"))` you want `if (symlink("/usr/lib64", "/lib64"))`

Comment: You have `mkdir /jail/bin; cp /bin/bash /jail/bin`.  But after `mkdir /jail/lib`, you need `cp /lib/* /jail/lib`.  Similarly for `/lib64`.  (If you don't want to copy all the libraries, you can use `ldd /bin/bash` to figure out just which ones `bash` needs.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I thought copying could be avoided by using mount as in the other example, e.g. `mount("/usr", "/jail/usr", NULL, MS_BIND | MS_REC | MS_RDONLY, NULL);` - is there a reason this doesn't work here?

Comment: A failure of `No such file or directory` from `exec` can mean that the executable wasn't found, or that a shared library wasn't found, or that the dynamic linker itself wasn't found.

Comment: I've never understood bind mounts so I don't know if they would work or not.  Copying is easy (but, yes, does waste space with duplicate copies).  Various kinds of mount tricks can work, but they're tricker, and arguably they detract from the whole point of a chroot jail, which is isolation.

Comment: It's also possible that your bind mount for the libraries worked, but that you're still missing the dynamic linker itself.  (I forget what it's called or where it is.)

Comment: @Steve Strangely, copying everything non-recursively in /bin and the other TLDs mentioned still doesn't seem to do the trick. I tried the symlink way as well and same thing with that